# an empty tearDown method makes the phpunit test pass

Tags: mysql, laravel, sqlite, phpunit

**I have the following Test class in Laravel 5.3, as you can see the `tearDown()` method is empty,I am using sqlite in memory for testing.
now the tests are being passed, but when i delete the empty `tearDown()` method, it throws a `foreign key constraint failed exception`,
I am using sqlite for the testing, `phpunit.xml` configuration is given below.
and I have tried to change the test database to mysql, that time everything works well(even without `tearDown()`). any idea why the absence of tearDown() method causes the error?
<?php

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Country;

class PhoneTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

        $this->seed(LocationsSeeder::class);

        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }

    public function test_we_can_make_number_international()
    {
        $phoneService  = resolve('Phone');
        $international = $phoneService->makeInternational('0507639889', Country::find(1));

        return $this->assertEquals($international, '+971507639889');
    }

   
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Environment :**
Laravel 5.3,
test db: sqlite - inmemory
phpunit 4.8.36
php - 7
**PHPUnit configuration**

> ```
>  <php>
>         <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
>         <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
>         <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
>         <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
>         <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
>         <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
>     </php>
> ```

**EDIT**: My migrations on a fresh db works properly, even up and rollback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the `DatabaseMigrations` trait, Laravel tries to execute the `migrate:rollback` command:

```
 $this->beforeApplicationDestroyed(function () {
     $this->artisan('migrate:rollback');
 });
```

And since your migrations are messy (that's why you're turning off FK constraints), it fails.

When you're placing `tearDown()` method, you're overriding the `tearDown()` method in the parent `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` class, so the `beforeApplicationDestroyed` callback is never executed.

The best way to handle this is to fix `down()` method in each migration, so each table could be deleted on `migrate:rollback` command execution. But you also could run [`migrate:reset`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#rolling-back-migrations) from `tearDown()` method. Or use `disableForeignKeyConstraints()` to disable FK constraints as you do in the `setUp()` method.

Comment: But one thing, why does this work when i change the test database to mysql?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Alexy Mezenin